# Is there any PSR / convention about Alternative Syntax?

Tags: php, coding-style, convention, psr-2, psr-1

I've seen a lot of posts talking about why alternative Syntax in PHP is good/bad.

It's not the topic, I'm a convention lover and **I want to know if there's about convention about it.** Have a clean code is one of my priority.

I'm pretty sure it's not a duplicate question but tell me if it's.

Comment: Why the downvote without comment ?

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org > recommendations (psr).

Comment: @BenRoob "View recommandations (PSRs)" isn't it the same ?

Comment: Actually, i was just pointing to the menu item "reco... (PSR)" ;)

Comment: @BenRoob oh.. my bad :)

Answer (score -1):

You can see all of the PSR recommendations at http://www.php-fig.org/.

The two PSR's concerning 'syntax' are

- PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/
- PSR-2 Coding Style Guide http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: And I've seen nothing about alternative syntax. It seem strange that there's no best practice or something else about it

Comment: I'm using PHP-CS-FIXER and it applies PSR1 + PSR2 and it notice nothing.

Comment: So you are already coding to the standard? In PHP Storm, I just select all and CTRL-ALT-L and it formats it compliantly where it can. Follow those two rules though and you'll be alright, employers love seeing PSR compliant on your CV!

Comment: CTRL+ALT+L isn't PSR compliant. I'm using it then php cs fixer and it change everytime. In both way. I'm using phpstorm too ofc :)

Comment: yeah, like i say, *where it can*, it wont rename `snake_cased_method()` to camelCase for instance!